# Mongoid - Use relation field in where query

Tags: mongoid

I have this models:

```
class Document1
  field privacy
  has_many events, :as => :target
end

class Document2
  field privacy
  has many_events, :as => :target
end

class Event
  belongs_to :target, :polymorphic => true
end
```

I need to do something like:

```
Event.where( :target.privacy => :public )
```

How could I do it ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot query a field from a relation table in Mongodb. Mongodb has no join concept. Also the dot notation wont work for you, as you are using a `belongs_to` and not a `embedded_in`. So you have a few options in here, you either can change your schema to use embedded relations, or you can do this in 3 separated queries, something like this:

```
ids = Document1.where(privacy: :public).pluck(:id) + Document2.where(privacy: :public).pluck(:id)
Event.where(target_id: ids).to_a
```

My advice is to review your schema, to make better use of embedded relations, but that depends on your use case.

Answer (score 0):

Your might want to take a look at the [dot notation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/document/#dot-notation) in MongoDB for [embedded documents](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/data-modeling/)

Comment: Don't works for me in Mongoid, always returns 0 results: Event.where( 'target.privacy' => :public )